# Reference in CV (moderncv) with footnote

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, moderncv

How can I add a footnote to one of the references `\cvreference` in a CV (document class: `moderncv`)? Most preferable I would like it to be behind the name of the person ...

My code is as following:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

% Define \cvdoublecolumn, which sets its arguments in two columns without any labels

\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

% usage: \cvreference{name}{address line 1}{address line 2}{address line 3}{address line 4}{e-mail address}{phone number}
% Everything but the name is optional
% If \addresssymbol, \emailsymbol or \phonesymbol are specified, they will be used.
% (Per default, \addresssymbol isn't specified, the other two are specified.)
% If you don't like the symbols, remove them from the following code, including the tilde ~ (space).

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\texttt{#6}\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle

\section{References}

\subsection{set in separate rows}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of California}
    {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
    {510-643-6234}%
    }
    {\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Columbia University}
    {990 Broadway}
    {New York, NY 10027}
    {khovanov@columbia.edu}
    {212-854-4186}%
    }

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Roman Bezrukavnikov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {77 Massachusetts Avenue}
    {Cambridge, MA 02139}
    {bezrukav@math.mit.edu}
    {617-253-2684}
    }
    {\cvreference{Tom Braden}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of Massachusetts}
    {Amherst, MA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {braden@math.umass.edu}
    {413-545-1732}
    }

\subsection{set in one row only (like your example)}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of California}
    {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
    {510-643-6234}\\[1em]
    \cvreference{Roman Bezrukavnikov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {77 Massachusetts Avenue}
    {Cambridge, MA 02139}
    {bezrukav@math.mit.edu}
    {617-253-2684}
    }
    {\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Columbia University}
    {990 Broadway}
    {New York, NY 10027}
    {khovanov@columbia.edu}
    {212-854-4186}\\[1em]
    \cvreference{Tom Braden}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of Massachusetts}
    {Amherst, MA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {braden@math.umass.edu}
    {413-545-1732}
    }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `moderncv` is not prepared to use footnotes.

If I understand right in your case you can add some commands to your preamble to get a footnote like this:

[image: resulting references]

Please see the following MWE (important code changings are marked with `<====` and please notice that I use version 2.0.0 of class `moderncv`, the current one):

```
\documentclass{moderncv} % Version 2.0.0

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\name{John}{Doe} % <====================================================

% Define \cvdoublecolumn, which sets its arguments in two columns without any labels
\newcommand{\cvdoublecolumn}[2]{%
  \cvitem[0.75em]{}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#1\end{minipage}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\listdoubleitemcolumnwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
    }%
}

% usage: \cvreference{name}{address line 1}{address line 2}{address line 3}{address line 4}{e-mail address}{phone number}
% Everything but the name is optional
% If \addresssymbol, \emailsymbol or \phonesymbol are specified, they will be used.
% (Per default, \addresssymbol isn't specified, the other two are specified.)
% If you don't like the symbols, remove them from the following code, including the tilde ~ (space).

\newcommand{\cvreference}[7]{%
\raggedright % <========================================================
    \textbf{#1}\newline% Name
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{\addresssymbol~#2\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{#3\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{#4\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{#5\newline}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{\emailsymbol~\url{#6}\newline}% <=======
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\phonesymbol~#7}}


\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
\vspace{3mm}
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}
\makeatother % <========================================================


\begin{document} 

\makecvtitle % <========================================================

\section{References}

\subsection{set in separate rows}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin\footnote{test1}} % <===
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of California}
    {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
    {510-643-6234}%
    }
    {\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov\footnote{test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 }}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Columbia University}
    {990 Broadway}
    {New York, NY 10027}
    {khovanov@columbia.edu}
    {212-854-4186}%
    }
\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Roman Bezrukavnikov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {77 Massachusetts Avenue}
    {Cambridge, MA 02139}
    {bezrukav@math.mit.edu}
    {617-253-2684}
    }
    {\cvreference{Tom Braden}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of Massachusetts}
    {Amherst, MA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {braden@math.umass.edu}
    {413-545-1732}
    }


\subsection{set in one row only (like your example)}

\cvdoublecolumn{\cvreference{Nicolai Reshetikhin}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of California}
    {Berkeley, CA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {reshetik@math.berkeley.edu}
    {510-643-6234}\\[1em]
    \cvreference{Roman Bezrukavnikov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Massachusetts Institute of Technology}
    {77 Massachusetts Avenue}
    {Cambridge, MA 02139}
    {bezrukav@math.mit.edu}
    {617-253-2684}
    }
    {\cvreference{Mikhail Khovanov}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {Columbia University}
    {990 Broadway}
    {New York, NY 10027}
    {khovanov@columbia.edu}
    {212-854-4186}\\[1em]
    \cvreference{Tom Braden}
    {Department of Mathematics}
    {University of Massachusetts}
    {Amherst, MA 94720-3840}
    {}
    {braden@math.umass.edu}
    {413-545-1732}
    }


\end{document}
```

Please see that I used command `\url` to typeset your urls and used `\raggedright` for a IMHO better layout.

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I was looking for! THANK YOU!