Problem with foonotes in moderncv
I am writing a cover letter using a moderncv template. In my letter, I would like to add footnotes which contain the contact details of my referees. When I do that using \footnote the desired footnotes appear, but without the numbering.
Here is a MWE.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}         
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{green}                              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{Random}{Person}
\address{Random street 1}{9999, Random city}{Random country}
\phone[mobile]{999}                   % optional, remove 
\begin{document}
\date{\today}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Sincerely,}
\makelettertitle
\vspace{0.5cm}

My referees are Jacky Chan\footnote{jackychan@random.xy} and Barbie Girl\footnote{barbiegirl@random.yx}.

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}

And here are the displayed footnotes.

How can I proceed to solve this issue ?
Thank you in advance for your help.

If the answer meets your request please accept it by checking the green tickmark on left side of the answer. Thank you!

The package moderncv does not define footnotes. This answer follows  this solution  to create them.

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}         
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\moderncvstyle{classic}                            
\moderncvcolor{green}                              
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% ******************************************* added
\makeatletter % <====== from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410535/161015
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
    \vspace{3mm}%
    \kern-3\p@%
    \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth%
    \kern2.6\p@}%
\newcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent%
    \hb@xt@2em{\hss\@makefnmark}\hspace{2.5\p@}#1}%
\makeatother %
%************************************************

\name{Random}{Person}
\address{Random street 1}{9999, Random city}{Random country}
\phone[mobile]{999}                   % 

\begin{document}
        
    \recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city} % <<<<<<<
    \date{\today}
    \opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
    \closing{Sincerely,}
    \makelettertitle
    
    My referees are Jacky Chan\footnote{jackychan@random.xy} and Barbie Girl\footnote{barbiegirl@random.yx}.
            
    \makeletterclosing  
\end{document}



Used **moderncv**[2024-07-18 v2.4.1 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class]

